# sourceMappingURL is cut short in browser

Tags: javascript, console, source-maps

I'm currently working on adding source-mapping to js file. The problem is that js file is linked to the map file something like this: `//# sourceMappingURL=C:/../../../cb.react.min.js.map`, but when i open the browser console, it tells me that 'DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for...' and the path was cut short like this: `example.com/dat/~/00ca23e74c61f3b8c08c92c4e6a8dfea/assets/js/C:`. What may be the cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

The path is being cut-off by the colon, because it is interpretting the "C" as the scheme for the URL. If you aren't sure what that means, then consider that a scheme you may be more familiar with might be "http".

Looking at what you have there, I do not think you should be specifying the "C:" which looks to be a local drive letter. You are combining that with a relative path and this looks like a possible mistake.

Did you mean something like:-

```
//# sourceMappingURL=../../../cb.react.min.js.map
```

Though that seems to be quite a lot of levels to traverse given that your source is in:

```
example.com/dat/~/00ca23e74c61f3b8c08c92c4e6a8dfea/assets/js
```

If your map file is in the same directory as your script, then it should probably just be:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=cb.react.min.js.map
```